# key with multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have a database MOVIES and it has 2 tables. 1 is MOVIE and the other is GENRE.

I want to be able to have row entry of MOVIE to be associated with multiple rows in the GENRE table. Can this be done with only 1 column in the MOVIE table?

I have seen examples of movie databases, but they only allow 1 genre to be mapped to a single movie. Is there a way to have multiple genres belonging to a single entry movie? I'm using mySQL to create the database.

Comment: From the answer I've been getting it seems a many-to-many relationship is needed. If I had a third table to track this relation would it have to look like this: [link]http://oi40.tinypic.com/343gs9i.jpg or could 1 row in the third table represent 1 entry from MOVIE and multiple entry from GENRE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a third table, `MOVIE_GENRE` that implements this many-to-many relationship. It has foreign keys into both the `MOVIE` and `GENRE` tables. A query to find list all the movies with their genres would look like:

```
SELECT m.title,
       IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(g.name), "") genres
FROM Movie m
LEFT JOIN Movie_Genre mg ON m.id = mg.movie_id
JOIN Genre g ON g.id = mg.genre_id
GROUP BY m.id
```

Comment: If I make a third table, does that mean that the entries for MOVIE_GENRE have 1 key from the movie table and 1 key from the genre table? If so, do I need to make a new row entry in MOVIE_GENRE for every genre that 1 movie is associated to?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means. That's how you represent the fact that a movie is in a genre, you add an entry to the table.

Answer (score 2):

You need a many-to-many or join table with 2 colums,

MovieID and GenreID

Having this structure will allow you to link a single movie to as many genres as you like